# fade navigation bar icons

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

How can I change navigation bar icons to dots?
You can see what I mean in the pictures[image: normal mode]
[image: fade mode]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I did it befor asking this question, but I didn't see any change

Comment: I tried it on the emulator and it worked, maybe the case is different with actual devices. This is the recommended way of doing it [as per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html). Check out [how to manage the system UI](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/index.html) and try different combinations of flags.